# Injecting dynamic HTML in React - CSS is not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Fetching dynamic HTML from an API, the HTML is loading fine but the **CSS** is not working for this new HTML.

Do you I need to reload the CSS.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Utility from "../common/Utility";

class Template extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  this.client_id = localStorage.getItem("client_id");
 }

 componentDidMount() {
   //fetching dynamic html
   Utility.ExecuteData("template", this.token, {
    client_id: this.client_id
   }).then(result => {
      var dynamic_html = document.getElementById("dynamic_html");
      dynamic_html.innerHTML = result.data[0].template;
     });
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <React.Fragment>
    <div id="dynamic_html" />
   </React.Fragment>
  );
 }
}

export default Template;
```

Comment: check if your styles are not `scope`d

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to get this to work but instead of `className` you'll need to use the usual HTML `class` attribute. I've used `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` here, but it's the same result if you set the `innerHTML` of the element like you did in your question.

```js
function Template({ html }) {
  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}} />
  );
}

const html = '<div class="heading">With style</div>';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Template html={html} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.heading {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'm posting it in an answer instead. 
I don't know how the html is being returned from the API but I assume the css is either inlined or included as a file in the remote HTML.

If the latter is the case, it might be a possibility that the url to the css file is relative, so calling the url from another server would result in a 404.

Comment: css is preloaded as an external file. html is coming with the classNames

Comment: HTML is perfectlly fine, css is preloaded but do not reflect the classes.

Comment: Do you mean that the html classes don't exist in the CSS?

Comment: found the issue, the html was coming with className(JSX format) not class.